# Installing VirtualBox on Manjaro i3, Error: target not found: virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, manjaro, i3

I've installed [*Manjaro i3*](https://manjaro.org/download/community/i3/) on my system and now I want to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) on it.

According to [Manjaro's VirtualBox Wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Virtualbox), I must install [virtualbox](/questions/tagged/virtualbox) with this command:

```
pamac install virtualbox $(pacman -Qsq "^linux" | grep "^linux[0-9]*[-rt]*$" | awk '{print $1"-virtualbox-host-modules"}' ORS=' ')
```

It gives me an option to choose some optional dependencies, and I choose `virtual-guest-iso: Guest Additions CD image` as I want to use *shared folder* later on. But then it throws this error:

```
Synchronizing package databases...
Error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/core.db: Unrecognized archive format
Error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/extra.db: Unrecognized archive format
Error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/community.db: Unrecognized archive format
Error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/multilib.db: Unrecognized archive format
Error: Failed to prepare transaction: target not found: virtualbox-guest-iso
```

If I run it again, it will simply throw this error:

```
Error: target not found: virtualbox
```

And now I can't do `sudo pacman -Syu` no more as it will throw the same error:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/core.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/extra.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/community.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/multilib.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: database 'core' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'extra' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'community' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'multilib' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
```

Now according to [[SOLVED] Unrecognized archive format (core.db,extra.db,etc)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135310), I can fix this by recursively removing everything in the `/var/lib/pacman/sync` directory. Now I can do `sudo pacman -Syu` just fine.

But if I run the first command to install `VirtualBox` it will throw the same error and everything repeats.

How can I fix this and install `VirtualBox` on `Manjaro i3`?

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still an issue for somebody: The Manjaro Wiki was updated and the erroneous command was removed, the command

```bsh
sudo pacman -Syu virtualbox linux54-virtualbox-host-modules
```

should install virtualbox assuming you are running a 5.4.X.X kernel

```
mhwd-kernel -li                                                           
> Currently running: 5.4.0-1-MANJARO (linux54)
> The following kernels are installed in your system:
>   * linux54
```